# AWK write to new column base on if else of other column

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a CSV file with columns A,B,C,D. Column D contains values on a scale of 0 to 1. I want to use AWK to write to a new column E base in values in column D.

For example:
if value in column D <0.7, value in column E = 0.
if value in column D>=0.7, value in column E =1.

I am able to print the output of column E but not sure how to write it to a new column. Its possible to write the output of my code to a new file then paste it back to the old file but i was wondering if there was a more efficient way. Here is my code:

```
awk -F"," 'NR>1 {if ($3>=0.7) $4= "1"; else if ($3<0.7) $4= "0"; print $4;}' test_file.csv
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
awk -F, 'NR>1 {$0 = $0 FS (($4 >= 0.7) ? 1 : 0)} 1' test_file.csv
```

Comment: Try my updated answer now... I am not sure you need `$3` or `$4` since you wrote column `D` which is `$4`

Comment: This works but i had to accept the other answer since it showed me how to output to a new file. Thanks for the short and sweet answer.

Comment: If nothing one should avoid unnecessary `cat`. So use: `awk -F, 'NR>1 {$0 = $0 FS (($4 >= 0.7) ? 1 : 0)} 1' test_file.csv > out.csv`

Comment: Also I believe you wanted to have `NR>1`  as a condition

Comment: could you explain this part: $0 = $0 FS

Comment: `FS` is field separator which is set to comma. `$0 = $0 FS` is same as `$0 = $0 ,` and then rest of it is conditional based on `$4` value. This way we didn't need to hardcode comma at multiple places, just once after `-F`

Comment: `1` is called default awk action which is to print the record.

Answer (score 1):

below awk command should give you intended output

```
cat yourfile.csv|awk -F "," '{if($4>=0.7)print $0",1";else if($4<0.7)print $0",0"}' > test_file.csv
```

Comment: Only worked when i use $3 instead of $4.  does the $0 mean the last column?

Comment: $0 means whole row, first column is $1, in this scenario you have 4 columns A,B,C,D i.e D should be $4